# How can you use form validation to go through multiple options?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, if-statement, boolean

The rest of the form validation worked fine, until I got to this: 
Sex must be a single character equal to M, m, F, or f

```
<script>
    function verify() {
        if (document.forms[0].age.value < 18) {
            alert ("Age must be between 18 and 30");
            return false;
        } 
        if (document.forms[0].age.value > 30) {
            alert ("Age must be between 18 and 30");
            return false;
        } 
        if (document.forms[0].age.value == "") {
            alert ("Age must be between 18 and 30");
            return false;
        } 
        if (document.forms[0].last.value == "") {
            alert ("Last name canot be empty.");
            return false;
        } 
        if (document.forms[0].sex.value !== "M" || "m" ||"F" ||"f")
            alert ("Please indicate your sex.");
            return false;
        } 
        alert ("Thank you for your submission.")
            return true;
    }
</script>
```

Expected: Pop ups for each issue with the form submission. I got a few before adding the bit about the sex validation.

Actual: Now no pop ups are occurring.

Comment: You can't combine tests like that; you need to state each expression in full. A simpler way is to test if the value is contained in the string `"MmFf"`.

Comment: In terms of form validation, there are a number of assumptions that a great form doesn't allow for (even in the US one can legally have only a single name. Your form locks those people out. Ask for their legal name, leave them to fill that in based on whatever that means? Also, asking for people's sex or gender is almost always setting yourself up for complaints, unless you have a genuine medical reason for knowing that information). That said, if you have a predefined set of mutually exclusive values, use a radio group, so people can't set an invalid value without DOM hackery.

Answer (score 1):

Your validation for sex is incorrect. When doing a boolean or (||) the condition must appear on all sides of the ||.

To fix this, change your code for sex validation to:

```
 var sex = document.forms[0].sex.value;
 if ( sex !== "M" || sex !== "m" || sex !== "F" || sex !== "f") {
     alert ("Please indicate your sex.");
     return false;
 }
```

As you can see, the if statement checks the sex against each value respectively.

Comment: This at least has my pop ups working again, but now, no matter what I put in the sex field, the pop up comes back to say "Please indicate your sex."

Comment: Replace every `||` with `&&`. (every value is not equal to at least three of those, so the test will always be positive currently)

Comment: Thanks Chris! I actually got that just now!